# Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verify'. , 'ImageTilingInfo' isn't a type.,Method not found: 'createTilingInfo, The argument type 'BorderRad

Tags: flutter

I've been getting these errors in my code, but really not sure what is the cause of it. I've upgraded a few of my packages so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it or not. Any help is appreciated.

Here  are the full error messages:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.15.1/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verify'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verify(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-8.0.2/lib/src/image/painting.dart:202:13: Error: 'ImageTilingInfo' isn't a type.
      final ImageTilingInfo info =
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-8.0.2/lib/src/image/painting.dart:203:11: Error: Method not found: 'createTilingInfo'.
          createTilingInfo(repeat, rect, destinationRect, sourceRect);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-8.0.2/lib/src/extended_image.dart:976:36: Error: The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable and 'BorderRadiusGeometry' isn't.
 - 'BorderRadius' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
 - 'BorderRadiusGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
              borderRadius: widget.borderRadius,
                                   ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/user/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Some packages were updated.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was **upgrade Flutter** so I have this trouble same like you.

So I just **downgraded Flutter** version and fixed this problem
I was doing this step next:

```dart
rm ios/Podfile
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
cd ios && pod update
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
flutter clean && flutter run
```

Hope that can help you.